# Remove comma in thousands in echarts4r

Tags: r, echarts4r

Here's a plot made with `echarts4r`:

```
library(tibble)
library(echarts4r)

data_test <- tibble(
  year = seq(1900, 1920, 1),
  variable = seq(200, 400, 10)
)

data_test %>%
  e_charts(year) %>%
  e_x_axis(year) %>%
  e_y_axis(variable) %>%
  e_line(variable)
```

How can I format the values on the x-axis so that I have `1900` instead of `1,900` for example?

I checked [here](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/grid.html) but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/173) for this question and this is the answer of the developer of `echarts4r` (I shortened it a little, see the link for the original answer).

There are **two solutions**.

**1)** Transform the variable `year` as a factor. This works only if there are no missing years.

```
library(tibble)
library(echarts4r)

data_test <- tibble(
    year = seq(1900, 1920, 1),
    variable = seq(200, 400, 10)
)

data_test %>%
    dplyr::mutate(year = as.factor(year)) %>% 
    e_charts(year) %>%
    e_line(variable)
```

**2)** Modify the JavaScript function. This is more robust, and it works when there are missing years.

```
library(echarts4r)

data_test <- tibble(
    year = c(1900, 1901, 1905),
    variable = 1:3
)

label <- list(
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
        'function(value, index){
            return value;
        }'
    )
)

data_test %>%
    e_charts(year) %>%
    e_y_axis(variable) %>% 
    e_line(variable) %>% 
    e_x_axis(serie = year, axisLabel = label)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but this should work :

```
data_test %>%
    e_charts(year) %>%
    e_x_axis(type='category') %>%
    e_y_axis(variable) %>%
    e_line(variable)
```

Adding options for a cleaner output :

```
data_test %>%
    e_charts(year) %>%
    e_x_axis(type='category',axisLabel = list(interval = 4),axisTick = list(inside=TRUE,alignWithLabel=TRUE,interval=4)) %>%
    e_y_axis(variable) %>%
    e_line(variable)
```

Output :

[image: eChart]

Comment: I posted the answer of the developer of `echarts4r` which I will validate later, but your solution works too. Thanks